# Removing root node in json

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json data stored in a variable.
var jsonstring;

**Json Data:**

```
{ "XYZ": { "abc":[{....}] } }
```

From above JSON Data, I should not have XYZ node. I need JSON Data as

```
{ "abc":[{....}] }
```

How can i remove using Javascript.

Comment: var newJson = theJson["XYZ"]

Answer (score 1):

If `jsonstring` is the JSON object, update it

```
jsonstring = jsonstring["XYZ"]
```

If `jsonstring` is a string, do like this.

```
var json = JSON.parse(jsonstring);
json = json["XYZ"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the property name you want to remove it's as easy as

```
json = json.XYZ;
```

if you don't know it and always want to remove the root note, use

```
json = json[Object.keys(json)[0]];
```